# If Israel legalized polygamy, how would the rabbis react?

Tags: state-of-israel, polygamy

If the Israeli government decided to legalize polygamy, how would the rabbinical establishment react?  Would they allow it religiously or not?  If not, on what grounds, given that the Torah allows it?

Rabbenu Gershom forbade it for Ashkenazim more than 1000 years ago, but his ban has expired.  Sephardim never forbade it, although they seldom practiced it.  (Having grown up in Egypt, I never heard of a single case.)  I know that a few Moroccans or Yemenites came to Israel in the 50s with more than one wife, and Israel "grandfathered" them, but it never allowed multiple weddings to take place on its territory.

Comment: the question you refer to does not answer my question unequivocally.

Comment: You're correct in that, @Maurice, but how could answers to *this* question be anything but opinion-based? (Another close reason)

Comment: The duplicate question clearly asks "Are there any laws on having more than 1 wife in Judaism today?" which is the same as what you ask. I think I'd close this again if reopened.